# How to modify an attributes of an ActiveRecord instance before render it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my Rails project, I have a model `class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base`, the class has an attribute called **compensation**, it is a [:jsonb](https://www.compose.com/articles/faster-operations-with-the-jsonb-data-type-in-postgresql/) data type in Postgresql.

```
  create_table "employee" do |t|                       
    ...
    t.jsonb    "compensation"
    ...
  end
```

The compensation contains salary, working_hours, start_from, and etc

```
compensation : {
  salary: 50000,
  working_hours: 230,
  start_from: 2018-12-21,
  ...
}
```

What I wanna do is that before an instance of Employee being rendered as JSON and response to the front-end, I need to remove the salary attribute in the **compensation**. In `employee_controller` I tried to use

```
def get_without_salary
  employee = Employee.find 2
  employee.compensation.delete :salary
  jsonapi_render json: employee
end
```

but the result JSON still contains the salary data. 
I can only make it works by:

```
  temp_compensation = employee.compensation.dup
  temp_compensation.delete :salary
  employee.compensation = temp_compensation
```

but it is too ugly and confused me why the first way failed.

Can someone explain to me why? Thanks

Comment: If you are using `jsonapi-utils` gem, then `jsonapi_render json: employee` statement fetches the Employee from the database again using `find_by` [explore the source](https://github.com/tiagopog/jsonapi-utils/blob/master/lib/jsonapi/utils/response/renders.rb#L33), and your delete will have no effect.

Comment: @awin it can't explain why the second way works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few days thinking, I came up the solution that first converts the active_record instance into a hash, then delete the salary in the hash, and then converts the hash into an active_record instance. This is a better solution comparing to mutating an object on the fly.

```
def get_without_salary
  employee = Employee.find 2
  filtered_employee = filter_salary employee
  jsonapi_render json: filtered_employee
end

def filter_salary(employee)
  record_hash = employee.as_json.deep_symbolize_keys!
  record_hash[:compensation]&.delete :salary
  Employee.new(record_hash)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems a rather tricky question. The options for `as_json` are the following:

1. `includes:` => used to include `has_many` and `belongs_to` associations
2. `methods:` => to include the result of a class method of the model
3. `except:` => prevent columns from showig
4. `only:` => only show specified columns

I tried some of them to specify only some attributes of the `jsonb` column but they either dont work or throw a `NoMethodError: undefined method 'serializable_hash' for #<Hash:0x00000005082eb0>` showing that it tries to serialize your `jsonb` but fails.

I think a clean way of doing it may be to have a method `filtered_compensation` in your model where you define the json you want to send and prevent `compensation` from showing.

```
def get_without_salary
  employee = Employee.find 2
  jsonapi_render json: employee.as_json(methods: [:filtered_compensation], except: [:compensation])
end
```

Where `filtered_compensation` is declared in your model

```
def filtered_compensation
  compensation.except 'salary'
end
```

I think it complies with being clean, separating concerns and makes your method `filtered_compensation` to be used elsewhere.

> Note that instead of having in your response the attribute `compensation`, you would find `filtered_compensation` as that is the name of the method.

Comment: Thank for your answer, but I need to keep compensation as the key name :(